# Python Flask Error - 2 separate database entries instead of 1

Tags: python, database, flask

I have been following a tutorial for creating my first website using Flask. I have been trying to add more things to it to test my knowledge.

There are 2 input boxes, one for a Note, and the other for the Title of said note.
Instead of Title and Comment as one entry, both inputs are added as comments and both titles are 'None'.

Example:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgOly.png)
Should be the following format in one entry:

[TITLE] [DATE] -
[NOTE]

**CLASS:**

```
class PNote(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = db.Column(db.String(10000))
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), default=func.now())
    title = db.Column(db.String(75))
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

**FUNCTION:**

```
@views.route('/public-note', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
@login_required
def public_note():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        title = request.form.get('title')
        note = request.form.get('note')
        if len(note) < 1:
                flash('Note is too short!', category='error')
        elif len(title) <1:
                flash('Title is too short!', category='error')
        else:
            new_ptitle = PNote(data=title, user_id=current_user.id)
            new_pnote = PNote(data=note, user_id=current_user.id)
            db.session.add(new_pnote)
            db.session.add(new_ptitle)
            db.session.commit()
            db.session.commit()
            flash('Note added!', category='success')
    return render_template("publicnote.html", user=current_user)
```

**HTML:**

```
{% extends "base.html" %} {% block title %}Home{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

<h1 align="center">Public Notes</h1>
<form method="POST" :>
    <textarea name="title" id="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Title"></textarea>
    <textarea name="note" id="note" class="form-control" placeholder="Write a comment..."></textarea>
    <br />
    <div align="center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Note</button>
    </div>
</form>
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush" id="pnotes">
    {% for pnote in user.pnotes %}
    <li class="list-group-item">{{ pnote.title }} {{ pnote.date }} <br /> {{ pnote.data }}
        <button type="button" class="close" onClick="deleteNote({{ pnote.id }})">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems clear that two different notes are being created. Perhaps you copy-paste the code when adding a new field?

This is the affected part:

```py
            new_ptitle = PNote(data=title, user_id=current_user.id)
            new_pnote = PNote(data=note, user_id=current_user.id)
            db.session.add(new_pnote)
            db.session.add(new_ptitle)
            db.session.commit()
            db.session.commit()
```

It should probably read:

```py
            new_note = PNote(title=title, data=data, user_id=current_user.id)
            db.session.add(new_note)
            db.session.commit()
```

Note how a single `PNote` object is created, and the `title` and `data` fields are assigned to different keywords.

You also don't need two `db.session.commit()`, so I've removed the second one.

Comment: Yes! This worked perfectly! I now understand what the code is doing. The 'note' is the the 'data' column in the database!

`new_note = PNote(title=title, data=note, user_id=current_user.id) ` worked a charm.
Thank you very much for your help!